# How to delete a Git repository in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to delete a Git repository in Azure DevOps project and cannot find an option for it.

The only option that I see for the Git repository is "Rename repository"

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Is this your only repository? If so, then Azure DevOps won't let you delete it. Create another repo, and it will then let you delete this one. Permissions could also be an issue. [Azure DevOps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg45s.png)

Comment: Thank you Casey. Permissions are definitely not an issue as I am the creator and the only user of the project and organization. Your answer seems spot on. Would you have a reference to Microsoft's resource on this issue?

Comment: Sure, sorry for the late response. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/delete-existing-repo?view=vsts)

Comment: Thanks. How I hate it when many many developers/UX persons disable/remove buttons/options with no explanation thinking it helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

1st you need to create an empty repo
then you can able to delete it..

Select Repos, Files.
From the repo drop-down, select Manage repositories.
Select the name of the repository from the Repositories list, choose the ... menu, and then choose Delete repository.
Confirm the deletion of the repository by typing the repo's name and selecting Delete.

Answer (score -5):

Go to your account, in the left-down cornet there is a setting link, press on that one, then Projects/Organisational settings/Projects. You will see a list of all your projects. Select the one you want to delete, then press delete from the button in the left-right corner.

Comment: The question was how to delete a repo not a project